# Плотная упаковка плавающих div по вертикали

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, html5, css3

Обычные плавающие div выстраиваются в строки с высотой самого высокого элемента. Вот так:
[image: Обычное поведение "плавающих" блоков]

Google+ делает вёрстку на порядок компактней и красивей. Вот так:
[image: Компактная вёрстка Google+]

Как можно добиться того, чтобы блоки подтягивались вверх, плотнее заполняя пространство? Желательно - без динамического высчитывания границ каждого элемента и абсолютного позиционирования.

Answer (score 2):

Стоит задумываться либо об одинаковости блоков по высоте, либо разбивать на несколько колонок и их уже заполнять блоками, а можно попробовать одни  влево, другие вправо... Скорее всего на 2-м скрине сделано в три колонки....
Так же можно воспользоваться свойством марджин коллапс и задать нижние отступы блокам....(но это при небольших разбегах высоты...)

Примерно вот накидал вариант со столбцами:

```css
#wrapper{
 width:770px;
 outline:1px solid #9F00BF;
}
#cols1{
 width:250px;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
}
#cols2{
 width:250px;
 margin: 5px  260px;
}
#cols3{
 width:250px;
 float:right;
 margin:0;
}

.a4{
 width:245px;
 height:150px;
 background:#66f;
 margin:5px;
}
.a5{
 width:245px;
 height:100px;
 background:#66f;
 margin:5px;
}
.a6{
 width:245px;
 height:150px;
 background:#66f;
 margin:5px;
}
.a7{
 width:245px;
 height:125px;
 background:#66f;
 margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="cols1">
  <div class="a4"></div>
  <div class="a6"></div>
  <div class="a5"></div>
  <div class="a7"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="cols3">
  <div class="a5"></div>
  <div class="a4"></div>
  <div class="a6"></div>
  <div class="a7"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="cols2">
  <div class="a4"></div>
  <div class="a7"></div>
  <div class="a6"></div>
  <div class="a5"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вопрос не про размеры. Общее в двух скринах то, что ширина у блоков на каждом из них одинаковая. Но во втором скрине они, как перевёрнутый тетрис, проваливаются в пустое пространство. А в первом нет. Вопрос - как сделать как во втором.

Comment: блоки со свойствами флоат при выстраивании ведут себя так: каждый следующий берет верхний край по нижнему предыдущего и если встретился на его пути блок длиннее то при движении он в него упрется.... отсюда читайте выше как с этим можно бороться.

Comment: И все же я считаю,что самый эффективный способ, это использовать колоночный макет. Создать несколько блоков длинной на всю страницу,расположить их колонками и наполнять блоками.

Comment: Просто блоки идут потоком. И в моей логике они заполняются как строчки в книге: слева направо. Просто при трёх колонках, если во второй что-то выпирает - не упирается в неё, а обходит и встаёт в первую. А в варианте с колонками они будут наполняться по очереди, а при реализации "бесконечной" прокрутки логика совсем потеряется. А если просто вставлять по очереди в три столбца, как бы выстраивая строки, то может так случится, что в первый попадёт три блока высотой 200рх, а в третий - по 50рх, от чего тоже логика строк совсем пропадёт.

Comment: Нет не будут они обходить... так уж устроено по умолчанию что упираться будут.....

Comment: Без специальной верстки, или без position absolute, одним css тут не обойтись. Вам выше правильно объяснили, если посмотрите исходный код g+, то увидите, что там используются вертикальные колонки. 
Если переживаете насчет колонок, то используете masonry (выше  сами ссылку указали)

Answer (score 1):

Не нашёл нигде CSS/HTML решения. Буду благодарен, если кто подскажет. Но есть вот такой вариант на jQuery: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Итоговый результат:
[image: Результат с Masonry]

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим Вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/53623)

Comment: Наверное, неправильно сформулировал: для меня это конечное решение, которое я сейчас использую.

Comment: Но это ведь мой вопрос. И для меня это - найденное решение, т.е. ответ на вопрос. И это решение кому-то может оказаться полезным. Если считаете, что этот ответ чем-то не соответствует вашим внутренним ценностям - могу удалить.

Answer (score 1):

Пусть блоки, множество блоков заключим в один див, с фиксированной шириной допустим 80%. Далее в стилях каждого из малых блоков внутри прописать

> display: block; height:100px width:30%; float:none

Вот так.

```css
.Osnovnoiblock{width:80%;}
.Malyiblock{display: block; height:100px width:30%; float:left; border:1px solid #000000;}
.text{width:100px;}
```

```html
<div class="Osnovnoiblock"><div class="Malyiblock"><div class="title">Заголовок</div><div class="text">Текст в блоке под заголовком</div></div><div class="Malyiblock"><div class="title">Заголовок</div><div class="text">Текст в блоке под заголовком</div></div><div class="Malyiblock"><div class="title">Заголовок</div><div class="text">Текст в блоке под заголовком</div></div><div class="Malyiblock"><div class="title">Заголовок</div><div class="text">Текст в блоке под заголовком</div></div><div class="Malyiblock"><div class="title">Заголовок</div><div class="text">Текст в блоке под заголовком</div></div><div class="Malyiblock"><div class="title">Заголовок</div><div class="text">Текст в блоке под заголовком</div></div><div class="Malyiblock"><div class="title">Заголовок</div><div class="text">Текст в блоке под заголовком</div></div><div class="Malyiblock"><div class="title">Заголовок</div><div class="text">Текст в блоке под заголовком</div></div><div class="Malyiblock"><div class="title">Заголовок</div><div class="text">Текст в блоке под заголовком</div></div><div class="Malyiblock"><div class="title">Заголовок</div><div class="text">Текст в блоке под заголовком</div></div><div class="Malyiblock"><div class="title">Заголовок</div><div class="text">Текст в блоке под заголовком</div></div><div class="Malyiblock"><div class="title">Заголовок</div><div class="text">Текст в блоке под заголовком</div></div><div class="Malyiblock"><div class="title">Заголовок</div><div class="text">Текст в блоке под заголовком</div></div><div class="Malyiblock"><div class="title">Заголовок</div><div class="text">Текст в блоке под заголовком</div></div><div class="Malyiblock"><div class="title">Заголовок</div><div class="text">Текст в блоке под заголовком</div></div><div class="Malyiblock"><div class="title">Заголовок</div><div class="text">Текст в блоке под заголовком</div></div><div class="Malyiblock"><div class="title">Заголовок</div><div class="text">Текст в блоке под заголовком</div></div></div>
```

Css:

```
.Osnovnoi block{width:80%;}
.Malyi block{display: block; height:100px width:30%; float:none}
```

Как поведет себя таблица?

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант 1:**

```css
.flexboxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height:200px;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flexboxes > div {width:200px;background-color:red;margin:3px;}
.block0 {height: 60px;}
.block1 {height: 80px;}
.block2 {height: 70px;}
.block3 {height: 90px;}
.block4 {height: 80px;}
.block5 {height: 100px;}
```

```html
<div class="flexboxes">
  <div class="block0"></div>
  <div class="block1"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
  <div class="block3"></div>
  <div class="block4"></div>
  <div class="block5"></div>
</div>
```

**Вариант 2 (с использованием скриптов):**

```js
$(function() {
  $('.flexboxes').masonry({
    itemSelector: 'div' // обращаемся к пунктам
  });
});
```

```css
.flexboxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height:200px;
  width: 630px;
}
.flexboxes > div {width:200px;background-color:red;margin:3px;}
.block0 {height: 60px;}
.block1 {height: 80px;}
.block2 {height: 70px;}
.block3 {height: 90px;}
.block4 {height: 80px;}
.block5 {height: 100px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://masonry.desandro.com/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>

<div class="flexboxes">
  <div class="block0"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
  <div class="block4"></div>
  <div class="block1"></div>
  <div class="block3"></div>
  <div class="block5"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Сам [использую](https://vostoksisters.github.io/gallery/somethingserious/) масонри для галереи, поддерживаю второй вариант) Но вот на css-tricks используется хак с инлайновыми элементами внутри стандартной разметки колоночного отображения текста. Вот [пример](http://codepen.io/VostokSisters/pen/vgOaQm?editors=1100). Способ хорош всем, но обратите внимание на нумерацию, она идет, собственно, как и положено колоночному способу отображения... Так что выбор в контексте использования, а выбор остается из двух - этот хак или скрипт масонри.